# Parse XML and get elements from it using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file such as below:

```
<host>
    <status state="up" reason="arp-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
    <address addr="128.208.188.2" addrtype="ipv4"/>
    <address addr="00:19:D1:3D:65:85" addrtype="mac" vendor="Intel Corporate"/>
    <hostnames>
        <hostname name="d0slf4.phys.washington.edu" type="PTR"/>
    </hostnames>
    <times srtt="1000" rttvar="5000" to="100000"/>
</host>

<host>
    <status state="up" reason="arp-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
    <address addr="128.208.188.3" addrtype="ipv4"/>
    <address addr="3C:94:D5:AC:18:7D" addrtype="mac" vendor="Juniper Networks"/>
    <hostnames>
        <hostname name="xe-0-3-2-&#45;1378.uwar-atg-1.infra.washington.edu" type="PTR"/>
    </hostnames>
    <times srtt="92000" rttvar="92000" to="460000"/>
</host>
```

The above code is a sample of two  objects in a large file. I'd like to get all the hosts in the file, and for each one, show it's name, ipv4 address, and vendor.

I've been doing searching for the last hour, and while I've found some good examples, none of them fit exactly what I need (sorry I'm new to XML parsing).

Here's the code I've been trying (incomplete, because I don't know where to go next):

```cs
string path = ""\\thor\test$\DataSubnetScans\" + _readableSubnet + ".xml";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(path);

XmlNodeList hosts = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("host");
foreach (XmlNode host in hosts) 
{
    // get elements (FQDN, IPv4, Vendor)
    XmlNodeList FQDN = this.GetElementsByTagName("hostname");
}
```

The line of code inside the foreach loop is wrong, it was just a guess. As you can see above, I'm trying to create a list of all the  elements, and then for each one, grab the hostname name, ipv4 address, and the vendor.

I understand that this is a little different than reading the text between the <> tags, and so I have to use something like `Attributes["name"].Value`.

I'm not sure if using `XmlNodeList` inside the foreach loop is the way to do this, but because each  element has 2  elements, I need a way to select them individually. Doing this should allow me to select the index right?

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks a bunch, and please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: For the XML you've given above, what is the exact result supposed to look like?

Comment: Check out [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). [This bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387067.aspx) may be particularly helpful.

Comment: @MarkCidade
 For the XML I've given, I'm trying to pull the hostname, IPv4 address, and vendor and create a table that lists them for each host

Comment: @Palpatim Many posts on MetaSE explain why tags in title are redundant. I don't see how this post can be an exception to it. It's pretty obvious from post and tags, moreover - C# is the most popular language for the .NET. Why do you think it is absolutely needed in the title?

Comment: @Fyodor Refering to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles, I fall in the camp of increasing title readability for humans, even though it may be redundant from a strictly technical standpoint. Removing C# from the question title made it too broad and difficult to categorize with a quick visual scan. My opinion, of course.

Comment: @Palpatim, Yeah, but please note from your link: "Note that the system automatically prefixes the title with the most common tag". So yes, readability increased, but only for specific cases, for example, viewing a list of questions tagged "xml". Seems like quite a rare case? See "Related" column at the right? If all questions in it contained "using C#" in title, it would look redundant and verbose, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following methods will be helpful:

- [XmlElement.GetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): retrieves the value of an attribute. In order to use it, you need to cast an XmlNode (as obtained from an XmlNodeList) to an XmlElement.
- [XmlNode.SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): selects a single node using an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) query.

You can retrieve the information as follows:

```
foreach (XmlNode host in hosts) 
{
    var hostname = ((XmlElement) host.SelectSingleNode("hostnames/hostname")).GetAttribute("name");
    var ipv4Address = ((XmlElement) host.SelectSingleNode("address[@addrtype='ipv4']")).GetAttribute("addr");
    var vendor = ((XmlElement) host.SelectSingleNode("address[@addrtype='ipv6']")).GetAttribute("vendor");
    // Add to list
}
```

The sample assumes that the structure of your Xml document is always the same and that all the elements are contained for a node. You might need to add some checks or refine the XPath queries if the structure varies.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using LINQ to XML:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");

var hosts = xmlDocument.Root.Elements("host");

foreach (XElement host in hosts)
{
   var hostName = (string) host.Descendants("hostname")
                  .First().Attribute("name");

   var ipv4 = (string) host.Elements("address")
               .First(x => (string) x.Attribute("addrtype") == "ipv4")
               .Attribute("addr");

   var vendor = (string) host.Elements("address")
                .First(x => x.Attribute("vendor") != null)
                .Attribute("vendor");
}
```